# My header is over the first 114.19px in the section when i navigate to it with the navbar?

Tags: html, css

My header is fixed and when i click on a link in my navbar the header always goes over the first 114.19px of the section. How can i fix this? I want the header to navigate 114.19px over the start of the section, so i can directly see the hole section. I would be glad if u can help me! I can also use javascript and jquery if i need this for the solution!

CSS

```
header {
  background-color: #ffcc99;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
left: 0;
  height: 114.19px;  
}
section {
  min-height: 100%
}

section#rec {
  min-height: 60%;
}

.reccomment h6 {
  padding-bottom: 3%;
  padding-top: 3%;
}

.reccomment p {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 6%;
}

section#opti,
#costs,
#pics {
  background-color: #a6a6a6;
}
```

HTML

```
<header>
  <div id="logo">
    <a href="#">
      <h1>Barbier Delo</h1>
    </a>
  </div>
  <nav class="nav">
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li><a href="#opti" class="test">Öffnungszeiten</a></li>
      <li><a href="#adress">Adresse</a></li>
      <li><a href="#costs">Preisliste</a></li>
      <li><a href="#date">Termine</a></li>
      <li><a href="#pics">Kundenfotos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#rec">Bewertung</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="burger">
      <div class="line1"></div>
      <div class="line2"></div>
      <div class="line3"></div>

    </div>
  </nav>
  <script src="app.js">
  </script>
</header>
<!--- WELCOME --->
<section id="welcome">
  <div class="headings">
    <h2>Willkommen bei Friseur Barbier Delo!</h2>
    <p>Dies ist die Website vom Friseur Barbier Delo aus Halle. Hier finden sie Adresse, Preisliste, Öffnungszeiten und können sogar einen Termin machen. Schauen sie sich mal um!</p>
  </div>
</section>
 ÖFFNUNGSZEITEN +
<section id="opti">

</section>
 ADRESSE
<section id="adress">

</section>
PREISLISTE
<section id="costs">

</section>
 TERMIN MACHEN 
<section id="date">

</section>
 KUNDENFOTOS 
<section id="pics">

</section>
BERWERTUNG 
<section id="rec">
  <div class="reccomment">
    <h6>Lassen sie eine Berwertung da!</h6>
    <p>Wenn ihnen der Service bei Barbier Delo gefällt oder sie Kritik zu äußern haben, dann klicken sie auf diesen Stern und lassen sie eine Berwertung da!</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, where did you get this decimal value of pixel for the height of the header. Try to put an integer value of the height. like `height: 115px` or whichever integer suits your case.

you can use something like:

```
window.scrollTo({
  top: $0.offsetTop - headerHeight, 
  behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

here $0 is the element you want to target. For `<section id="welcome" />` your code would be

```
window.scrollTo({
  top: document.getElementById("welcome").offsetTop - headerHeight, 
  behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

Also if you need support for old browsers which do not support  `window.scrollTo({top: X})`, you need to wrap this under `try-catch` and use `window.scrollTo(X);` in the catch.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo